# Using TTreeview as a menu

Tags: delphi

Im using delphi's ttreeview as an 'options' menu. how would i go upon selecting the next node at runtime like a previous and next button? i tried the getprev and getnext methods but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Here you have the 'Next' behavior. For 'Previous' I leave as exercise for you: :-)

```
procedure TForm8.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  crt: TTreeNode;

begin
  with tv1 do //this is our tree
  begin
    if Selected=nil then
      crt:=Items[0] //the first one
    else
      crt:=Selected.GetNext; //for previous you'll have 'GetPrev' 

    if crt<>nil then //can be 'nil' if we reached to the end
      Selected:=crt;
  end;
end;
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some space in tree item to store pointer to you correct page.

But - if you have some time - try to explore [Virtual Treeview](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38) - it's Delphi's best treeview component.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do this:

```
type TfrmMain = class(TForm)
...
   public
      DLLHandle : THandle;
      function GetNodePath(node: TTreeNode; delimiter: string = '\') : String;

...

function TfrmMain.GetNodePath(node: TTreeNode; delimiter: string = '\') : String;
begin
   Result:='';
   while Assigned(node) do
    begin
      Result:=delimiter+node.Text+Result;
      node:=node.Parent;
   end;
   if Result <> '' then
      Delete(Result, 1, 1);
end;

...
```

here is how to use it: on your treeview's click or doubleclick event do this

```
...
var
   path : String;
begin
   path:=GetNodePath(yourTreeView.Selected);
   ShowMessage(path);
...
```

if you have a 'Item 1' and a subitem called 'Item 1' and click on Item 2 than the message should be 'Item 1\Item 2'. By doing this you can have a better control...

hope this gives you another idea to enhance your code